# Getting the same data from a Search and Export using different Views in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, view

I have two tables in a database.  One table is a master table and the other table is a child table. When the user does a search, they query only for records in the master table and when then click a plus sign, it does a search for child records.  The query is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
GROUP BY id
LIMIT 0,10;
```

I only inner join to the child table (TableB) if the user selects search criteria in that is applicable to the child table, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b on b.MasterId = a.id
GROUP BY a.id 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

The above all works fine except when I have to export, when the user exports, it uses a different view of the data, there is no master and child level, it is a flatted out result, so for example, when I do a LIMIT 0,10 on the search, it brings back 10 Master records, but if I have 1 master record with 10 child records, the export will only bring back the 10 records that include both master and child information, but it will only be the first master record from the search and it may not even be the same record, because I am querying against views.  The query for export might be:

```
SELECT * FROM TableC
LIMIT 0,10;
```

`TableC` is basically a view of the flattened data from `TableA` and `TableB`, but because it is flatted, applying a `LIMIT`, does not apply properly.

Is there a way to get around to this problem?  Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `limit` you should include an `order by`.  MySQL guarantees the ordering after a `group by`.  So, try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableC
ORDER BY aid
LIMIT 0,10;
```

As a note:  this works in MySQL because of the guarantee of the ordering after a `group by`.  This is not ANSI standard and does not apply to other databases.